# How to join text only elements in list, ignoring numeric strings and other elements?

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a list with elements like

```
["xyz", "abc", "123,123,123", 456.78 , "pqr"]
```

I want to join only the elements that are strings into a single string, and convert numeric strings into numbers, like

```
[ "xyzabcpqr", 123123123, 456.78]
```

How can this be done in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not very beautiful but it works

```
import numbers
L_in = ["xyz", "abc", "123,123,123", 456.78 , "pqr"]
L_out = []
char_str = ""

for i in L_in:
    if(isinstance(i , numbers.Number)):
        L_out.append(i)
    elif any(c.isdigit() for c in i):
        L_out.append(int(''.join([c for c in i if c.isdigit()])))
    else:
        char_str += i

L_out = [char_str]+L_out
```

Result:

```
['xyzabcpqr', 123123123, 456.78]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

it goes like this:

```
import numbers
mylist = ["xyz", "abc", "123,123,123", 456.78 , "pqr"]

    for i in mylist:
        if(isinstance(i , numbers.Number)):
            pass
        else:
            print (i)
```

**IMPORTANT**: i copied your list items and checked that out , result was like this :

```
'xyz' , 'abc' , '123,123,123' , 'pqr'
```

you can see that it prints 123,123,123 as it is , that's because you passed that element in array as a string (**"123,123,123"**) if you pass that as a int number like **123123123** the for loop will pass that too.

**Edited** 
for that case you can tweak that code a little bit to this:

```
import numbers
mylist = ["xyz", "abc", "123,123,123", 456.78 , "pqr"]


for i in mylist:
    # check if there is a number as element
    if(isinstance(i , numbers.Number)): 
        pass
    # check if there is a string element in array that includes any digits
    elif(any(element.isdigit() for element in i)):
        pass
    # after filters that we applied , then print the element
    else:
        print (i)
```

the result will be `xyz , abc , pqr`

i think you asked for join the elements in array , and for that you can use `join(yourList)` instead of `print(i)` or what ever functionality you want...
hope it help you to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks! The number as a string is something that is present in the list, and I need to process and ignore it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex with one loop:

```
data=["xyz", "abc", "123,123,123", 456.78 , "pqr",11111111]

import re
string_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z]+'
num_pattern1=r'[0-9.,]+'

s_=[]
i_=[]
for i in data:
    a=re.search(string_pattern,str(i))
    b=re.search(num_pattern1,str(i))
    if a!=None:
        s_.append(a.group())
    elif b!=None:
        if '.' in b.group():
            i_.append(float(b.group()))
        elif ',' in b.group():
            i_.append(int(b.group().replace(',','')))

        else:
            i_.append(int(b.group()))


print(["".join(s_)]+i_)
```

output:

```
['xyzabcpqr', 123123123, 456.78, 11111111]
```